# Changing the pitch of raw waveform data in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, audio, waveform

I am trying to modify waveform data that I am getting through [waveInOpen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743847(v=vs.85).aspx) via [WAVEHDR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743837(v=vs.85).aspx)-structs. I want to change the pitch of the sound.

All I have is a pointer to the raw audio data and the number of the used bytes.

I am a little lost because I cant find any examples on how to do this.
I would be really thankful for a starting point on how to edit raw waveform data (or even an example of how to change the pitch would be really awesome).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the pitch by changing the playback rate. Say for example you recorded a waveform at 48kHz sampling rate and then when you played it back you told the system that the sample rate was 96kHz. The pitch of everything would double. Also the playback duration would halve which you may not want. An alternative to changing the sample rate is to add or remove samples to achieve basically the same effect. Contrary to the other answer it is not as arbitrary as adding or removing samples. When you remove samples you need to apply low pass filtering to prevent aliasing. And when inserting samples you need to apply an interpolation filter. These are not trivial if you don't have a signal processing background.  Finally, if your goal is to shift the pitch but leave the duration at the original duration then it you need to look at something like a phase vocoder.

Comment: Changing the playback rate isnt an option because I am modifying the waveform "live" (it's a voice changer that modifies the wave sound in realtime) so I guess my only option is to modify the waveform bytes.

What do you mean by removing samples? Your answer inspired me to remove every second byte and replace it with the byte next to it. That way I halfed the waveform. But that turned the waveform into just one loud noise.

Comment: @moccajoghurt. The samples are probably 16-bits so you would need to remove every second *pair* of bytes. That aside if you don't low pass filter first then you'll get aliasing where higher frequencies of the original signal which no longer fit into the bandwidth will fold back down. For example if your at 48kHz and have a tone at 20kHz, then remove every other sample, the 20kHz becomes 40kHz which is 16kHz above the nyquist frequency of 24kHz so it will fold down and show up at 8kHz.